# how to get permission of google plus domain Api?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I enabled the google+ domain api in developer console.
When hitting the service of post or getting list activity I am getting

> 403,forbidden

message is

> you don't have the permission.

Comment: Could you post some code? I want to refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 403 OK
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}

Comment: You expect us to help you right? Then put your c# code in your question. Next time you comment without putting you code above you will get my first down vote ever.